# Why no error in one file and error in other - "Non Static Member Reference mush be relative to specific object"

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I have a texture manager that I am running as singleton, and wish to make a objectmanger in the same way..

Anyway.. I copied the EAXACT code that is working 100% in the texturemanager but in the object manager it is giving me this error "Non Static Member Reference mush be relative to specific object"

I assume it has something to do with the `std::map`?

Here is my 100% working textureManager header and cpp file.
http://ideone.com/6bZQG | http://ideone.com/jjo2M

Here is the start of the ObjectManager that is NOT working...
http://ideone.com/rhSim | http://ideone.com/uLj4X

Now, basically the pointer to `std::map` is where I am getting the error.. (line 23 of ObjectManager.cpp) The `delete` call in `destroy()` is giving me that error and anywhere else (if I make a new function. Yet the timer variable is working as expected.

Is there some fancy way I am supposed to do a pointer to a `std::map`? As far as i can tell this code is 100% the same as the code for the texture manager?

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Why `delete gameObjects;` and not `delete  instance->gameObjects;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To roughly repeat what I said on IRC:

- You do not want a pointer to `std::map` -- it does not save you any copies, and will likely cost more memory and effort to maintain.
- If you don't care about the order in which the various singletons are destroyed, use a `unique_ptr` for them: see [header](http://ideone.com/LwuNv) and [implementation](http://ideone.com/0XWaW).
- Boost has a perfectly fine noncopyable, use that (your implementation still allowed assignment, for example).

As to why your version was not working: on line 23 of your implementation file, you were referring to `gameObjects` without specifying which instance you meant.  You probably meant `instance->gameObjects`.